# How to synchronize 2 docker container's overlay2 filesystems?

Tags: docker

I happen to use docker in a questionable way for a specific purpose:

I have a container with a few development tools and their configurations. These are typically tools found in operating systems that are configured with dotconf files usually found in home directories (like tmux, vim, git, programming languages...). This is normally handled by configuring an OS with tools and dotfiles.

But with the setup becoming more complex over the years, properly setting up a new OS is becoming very hard. On the other hand, moving a container around machines is very simple. So for that precise case, I happen to use docker in a way that goes against the "docker way". But that is really comfortable to me.

That being said, I also want to synchronize the container's filesystem with another container (which, in my understanding is definitely not the "docker way", but yet.) I want to run 2 instances of the same image, on different machines. Then I want to synchronize their read write layer that is on top of the image. So when a file is created, deleted or modified on one, this is replicated on the other.

I was thinking of using rsync or unison to do that. But I don't know how the overlay2 driver works. Are the directories in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/<container-id>` the actual containers filesystem layer? Or should it be mounted? I saw some people mount their containers filesystem on the host with the device mapper driver fairly easily. Would that make sense with overlay2?

Comment: Might be better to use a bind mount rather than a volume; and then rsync the directories at the host level.

Comment: Absolutely. I would like to do that at host level. How would you do that with the overlay2? I'm not sure the folder in `/var/lib/docker` are all there is to it.

Comment: No, you don't want a volume, use bind mount. It's just a normal directory wherever you want it.

Comment: There is something I don't understand. You talk about a volume in your comments, but I never mentioned it. Is there something in my description that could be seen as a volume and I did not realize that? I know what a bind mount is, I just don't know what on the filesystem to bind mount. I am only interested in the filesystem layer of the container, which sits on top of the stack in the image. I use the overlay2 driver and I'm not sure where this data actually is. I can see there are some files present on the container and not in the image in the aforementioned path, but is it enough to bind?

Comment: `overlay2` is a storage driver *for volumes*. A bind mount is literally just making a file path from the host accessible to the Docker container, eg: `docker run -v /my/path/on/host:/my/container/path ubuntu` for example. You don't need to do **anything** with `overlay2`, volumes, drivers, or anything this way. Just rsync your path on the host and use it on your container and call it a day.

Comment: ok I'll try that tkanks. If you want to make it an answer then I can accept it.

Comment: by the way, where did you see that overlay2 is for volumes? I'm interested in that. On that page (https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#image-and-container-layers-on-disk) I understand this driver is used to unify the image + the container directories to create the container filesystem, without any volume.

Comment: Ah - You're absolutely correct, while the storage driver will affect volumes - it looks like it's certainly not limited to volumes, and also affects the underlying filesystems of each container. You taught me something as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option here is to use a bind mount. This changes your initial design a bit - but it will likely be the cleanest, and easiest to implement.

First things first - you'll want to ensure that any files that you want to have synced are in a specific folder; so rather than rsyncing the entire underlying filesystem - you'll just do, for example `/app/my_files` *inside your container* and set your application to read/write from there.

Now - create your directory and setup the rsync between your machines; let's say it's at `/rsync`

Lastly - run your containers and use a bind-mount; which if you're just bringing up a container would look like: `docker run -d -v /rsync:/app/my_files my_image`

Answer (score 0):

After reading this page: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/ and experimenting with image / container creation and deletion, I have found out a few things.

When creating an image, the folder `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` is populated with a new folder, called with what seems to be a hash (let's call it `123`), and is itself populated with the image content / filesystem.

Then when creating the container from this same image, two more folders get created inside `/var/lib/docker/overlay2`, also named with what seems to be another hash, with one of them having `-init` at the end. Let's call them `456` and `456-init`. They seem to contain the container layer.

When looking at the output of `docker inspect <container-name>`, the `GraphDriver` section has some info about how docker uses the overlay2. The lower dir contains the init container dir + the image dir as in: `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/456-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/123/diff`. I don't fully understand how that works, but I understand that I am not interested in the lower dir since it should be the image dir in read only mode. And that is something I already have on all hosts and thus do not need to sync.

Then in my understanding the upper dir in overlay2 is the read write layer that the container uses on top of the image layer. In the `GraphDriver` this is found to be `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/456/diff`. That is the directory that gets the changes made inside the container. I could not find the documentation so I experimented a bit and found out that this upper dir never changed during the life of the container. I stopped and started it and the upper dir stayed the same. Then when removing the container this folder is deleted. And when creating the container again, a new folder with a different name is created.

So it looks like what I need to sync is this upper dir, which can be found with `docker inspect`. I'll experiment a bit more with that.